# Creating a server which supports multi client to connect in C# dot net

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption

I'm trying to write a chat application in C# dot net which has two side, a server side and client side.
The server side is unique but the client side could be more than one and data transmission should be encrypted, indeed I would implement encrypted data communication on the both sides.

- As a big picture I'd ask what stuffs I need to do?
- What I need is, Consider the server side creates a socket and two
  clients are going to send data (for ex: client0 gives the address of
  client1) then how the server should route the data to the
  destination(in this case client1)?
- How data encryption should be implemented and which data
  cryptographic encryption should be used and how?

I think thought of data encryption might be more complicated task in this time so I'd write the project without implementing data encryption at first ?

Thanks for pretty ideas.

Comment: The question is interesting, but it is too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @mybirthname I know it has a long story but just in brief and the big picture point of view ? :)

Comment: there is an infinite number of examples here: https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20chat%20sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) (client) and with [TcpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx) (server)
while the communication and data transfer can be used with Threads / async Tasks to get asynchronous and multi threaded functionality.

read this:
http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

*EDIT:

it's hard to explain without providing you at least small sample of a project and code, hence I posted the link above which I think can really help you to start off.

as for the routing from 1 client to another, 
you can do it in several ways. 
one way is to give each client a unique ID or maybe use a unique username (same as most chats out there) and send that unique username. you can create a string on each time you send data with delimiters and parse it when received.

for example:

this will be on the client's side:

```
string FullMessage = "$#1name" + "yourName" + "$#2name" + "$#1message" + "YourMessage" + "$#2message");
```

this will be on the server's side:

```
string MessageRecieved = GetSubstringByString("$#1message", "$#2message", FullMessage);
string Name = GetSubstringByString("$#1name", "$#2name", FullMessage);

public string GetSubstringByString(string startString, string endString, string fullString)
{
    return fullString.Substring((fullString.IndexOf(startString) + startString.Length), (fullString.IndexOf(endString) - fullString.IndexOf(startString) - startString.Length));

    }
```

Comment: Could you give more explanation ? what about the routing data on the server side ? thanks.